# Proper way to change bashrc when making a ubuntu package or python package

Tags: python, bash, package

I'm planning to make a program which should edit the users bashrc.

In the case of python library, I'd like to add a binary to /bin/ automatically. When it is executed, then it should add a function and call it every time when a user is loggd in to bash, so I definitely should change bashrc.

In the case of ubuntu package, it should do same job as desribed above.

However, adding some function to bashrc seems not a proper solution because when it is removed, it should edit bashrc again but if there is any small change of added codes removal of package might make some dummy codes on bashrc.

Is there any neet solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming ubuntu is somewhat like debian.

/etc/profile.d is probably the best way.

Don't edit any files just drop a file into profile.d that checks for bash and that your package is installed and then does whatever it needs.